# GET works but POST doesn't for silent login

Tags: php, http, https

We have 2 systems one in PHP and one in asp.net which currently require separate logins even though both use the same username/password information.

As a quick (and temporary) fix I thought I might be able to amend the PHP login page to pass the login details to the asp.net page behind the scenes so the user could be logged in automatically to both systems rather than having to enter their credentials again when navigating to a different page.

This works fine when I use a GET to pass the parameters but of course the GET parameters including the password get stored in the server log which is not a good idea.

So I would like to use POST instead, but I can't get it to work.  I used the CURL-less method in [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) (code below) and it appears to work but the asp.net login process creates secure cookies and while they are stored if I GET the page they are not being stored when I POST to it instead.

```
$url = 'https://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

I have tried something similar with CURL in the past so I know that CURL creates it's own browser context but I thought a straight POST request would work, however it seems to be behaving much the same as CURL.

Is there some way to get this to work or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how POST works?  If so could somebody point me at a good explanation.

Comment: Disable logging of GET requests on your ASP.NET webserver and you do not need to solve this problem any longer :)

Comment: Acutally, why not just use a CURL request from PHP and send Custom post parameters. That should work.

Comment: @Panama Jack CURL creates it's own context so any cookies stored in the CURL session are only accessible through CURL, I need the cookies to be accessible to the user's normal browser session.